# Quadratic taylor polynomial of $f(x, y) = x^4 + x^2y^2 + y^4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> Given
>
> $$f(x, y) = x^4 + x^2y^2 + y^4,$$
>
> I would like to calculate the taylor polynomial of degree $2$ at $(0, 0).$

**Approach**

This exercise confuses me. I simply tried to follow the algorithm that was given to us, but my polynomial disappears completely.

First, I calculated the derivatives:

$$f_x = 4x^3 + 2xy^2 $$

$$f_y = 4y^3 + 2yx^2 $$

$$f_{xy} = f_{yx} = 4xy$$

$$f_{xx} = 12x^2 + 2y^2 $$

$$f_{yy} = 12y^2 + 2x^2$$

Now, I have to put in the point $(0,0)$ in the derivatives, but this doesn't leavy any term at all to calculate the polynomial.

Is it possible that the exercise has a mistake in it?

Comment: Sure, it is possible that there is a mistake in the exercise. It is also possible that this exercise is a trick question, and the correct answer, as per your calculations, is that the quadratic Taylor polynomial of $f$ is $0$. After all, $f$ only contains terms of degree $4>2$.

Comment: True. I guess there's a mathematical law for questions like this, isn't it? Something like: "If the degree of the polynomial is higher than the degree  of the taylor polynomian, then ..."

Comment: I hazard a guess that in the coming problem session a teacher will give a speech explaining how a Taylor polynomial of a polynomial consists of the low degree terms (if there is a mixture of terms of varying degrees, the lowest ones may survive). And remind you all that the exact same thing happened with single variable polynomials and their Taylör polynomials. At least if I were given the task of overseeing the said problem session :-)

Comment: I'm preparing for an exam, therefore, there won't be any other lecture. :D But maybe we were already told something about it, but I've fortgotten it.

Comment: Maybe you were supposed to figure it out yourself. See, you have the algorithm: find the derivatives, then the second derivatives, then plug them in such-and-such way, just as you did. The algorithm is correct, 100% applicable, and you know it well. What could go wrong? Nothing, except this one thing: the correct answer may look unusual to the point that you'd refuse to believe it. Yes, this is your 2nd degree polynomial: $0+0x+0y+0x^2+0xy+0y^2$. $0$ is a number as good as any other, after all.

Comment: Well, I guess that's fine then. :-) Thanks!